# How to sort a massive/object

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I've got a massive `$events`. 
To output information of this massive I do:

```
<?php foreach ($this->events as $usern): ?><?php foreach ($usern as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->resource_types; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->resource_ids; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->action; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->owner($user->originator); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->event_date; ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php //if($this->canManageBusiness($user->id)): ?>

            <?php // endif ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?><?php endforeach ?>
```

Interesting that I may use both `$user->id` and `$user['id']` sintax. But never mind. 
How can I sort this massive by `$user['id']` desc?

Edited:
I take data from database, but not usual way, so I can't use sql syntax so sort results:

```
$events[] =$this->_dbTable->fetchAll($this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable, array('id','resource_types','resource_ids','action','originator','event_date'))->where('resource_types = ?', 'business')->where('resource_ids',$bus->id));
$events[] =$this->_dbTable->fetchAll($this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable, array('id','resource_types','resource_ids','action','originator','event_date'))->where('resource_types = ?', 'document-type')->where('resource_ids',$dt->id));
return $events
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? If you read it from some database, sorting there would be much easier.

Comment: Ok, with THIS manner of selecting data... But is there really no `->sort('id', 'desc')` method?

Comment: there is a method, but if i use it, I get two sorted parts of the massive, i want to sort the WHOLE massive

Comment: this can also be done by creating sql views (and/or by using unions)

Answer (score 2):

Do you read the data from a database? then simply add to your query `SORT BY id DESC`

else you may use usort() in PHP:

```
usort($events, function ($a, $b) { return $a->id - $b->id; });
```

Comment: I read it from database, but I can't sort this way, because my massive includes data from different select operations

Comment: You've already heard from subselects? like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT big from table) SORT BY id DESC` (or is this simply too slow?)

Comment: You can sort anything in the RDBMS. They are used for that, among other uses. If you found yourself needing to sort a data-set, do it in the RDBMS, not in the application language unless there's some huge, huge logical mistake that prevents the db from sorting it efficiently.

Comment: after trying usort as you wrote, i started to get an error, so this method doesn't work. I tried some array-sorting functions before asking a question, but do not know how to use them in this very situation.

about subselects, maybe I can use one select in place of several and sort results, it would be better, I think, but, again, I do not know how

Comment: @user1956641 Would you like to show me the exact structure of `$events`? I think I'm having a lack of information

Comment: I do not know the structure myself, I wrote how I collect data and output it.

Comment: @user1956641 `var_dump()` it?

Comment: @user1956641 Ok, you use Zend... Then I don't really know how to sort it as I'm unable to read the protected data without reflection...

Answer (score 1):

adding an `order()` to the query doesn't get you there?

```
$events[] =$this->_dbTable->fetchAll($this->_dbTable->select()
    ->from($this->_dbTable,
        array('id','resource_types','resource_ids','action','originator','event_date'))
    ->where('resource_types = ?', 'business')
    ->where('resource_ids',$bus->id)
    ->order('id DESC'));
$events[] =$this->_dbTable->fetchAll($this->_dbTable->select()
    ->from($this->_dbTable,
        array('id','resource_types','resource_ids','action','originator','event_date'))
    ->where('resource_types = ?', 'document-type')
    ->where('resource_ids',$dt->id)
    ->order('id DESC'));
return $events
```

it looks to me like this is all coming from the same table, if so why not build a single query?

Maybe something like:

```
$events[] = $this->_dbTable->fetchAll($this->_dbTable->select()
              ->from($this->_dbTable,
                   array('id','resource_types','resource_ids','action','originator','event_date'))
              ->where('resource_types IN (?)', array('business', 'document-type'))
              ->where('resource_ids IN (?)', array($bus->id, $dt->id))
              ->order('id DESC'));
```

Not real sure if this will help get you there, maybe.

Comment: this variant is interesting, and I guess it could work if only I didn't populate $events with elements in different loops

Answer (score 0):

This sucks, since you have to go through the list twice, but you could...

```
$events_arr = array();
<?php foreach ($this->events as $usern): ?><?php foreach ($usern as $user): ?>
    $events_arr[$user_id][] = $usern; endforeach; endforeach;
ksort($events_arr);
```

Now you can use events arr, which is sorted by user_id

```
foreach ($events_arr as $user_id => $usern) {
  foreach ($usern as $user) {
    echo $user_id . ": " . $user->action;
  }
}
```

Comment: but where do i get $user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to denormolise my DB Table to make the process of selection data easier. Let's see if it get's better.